# passing arguments to a click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have an `onclick` event that passes a `$(this)` argument to a function.

```
<tr class="myTr">
  <td>
    Han Solo
  </td>
</tr>  

<script>
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  doSomething($(this));
});
</script>
```

Now, I want to add another step. I want to show a button, and after this button is click, `doSomething()` is supposed to be called.

```
<tr class="myTr">
  <td>
    Han Solo
  </td>
</tr>  
<button id="myBtn" style="display:none">Submit</button>

<script>
  $('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
    $('#myBtn').show();
  });
  $('#myBtn').click(function(){
    doSomething(???);
  });
</script>
```

How do I pass the `$(this)` to the second click event?

I could easily store the `$(this)`as a tag of the button, something like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  $('#myBtn').attr('origin', $(this));
  $('#myBtn').show();
});
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  var tr = $(this)attr('origin');
  doSomething(tr);
});
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Use a data attribute instead of attr. `$('#myBtn').data('origin', $(this));` and `$(this).data('origin');`

Comment: use global variables?

Comment: other option is to unbind and rebind it the click event, updating the script to use the variable with a closure. I would use the data attr.

Comment: I wanted to try it without global variables or attributes (or data attribute)

Comment: Well you need to store it somewhere...

Comment: so there is not other way?

Comment: The possible solutions are listed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the state in some manner

Data attribute:

```
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  $('#myBtn').data('origin', $(this)).show();
});
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  var tr = $(this).data('origin');
  doSomething(tr);
});
```

Local Variable

```
(function () {
    var active;
    $('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
      active = $(this);
      $('#myBtn').show();
    });
    $('#myBtn').click(function(){      
      doSomething(active);
    });
}());
```

Rebind the event:

```
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  var active = $(this);
  $('#myBtn')
    .off("click.tr")
    .on("click.tr", function () {
      doSomething(active);
    })
    .show();
});
```

CSS class:

```
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  $(".myTr.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $('#myBtn').show();
});
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  var tr = $(".myTr.active");
  doSomething(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$.proxy` from jQuery

```js
$('body').on('click','.myTr',function(){
  $('#myBtn').show();

    $('#myBtn').off('click').on('click', $.proxy(function(e) {
        doSomething(this)
        // how you access the context of the button is using $(e.currentTarget)
    }, this));
});


window.doSomething = function(elem){
 console.log(elem)
}
```

```css
#myBtn{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="myTr" value="test">
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="button">
```

Comment: There is a flaw in this code,  you need to unbind the last click attached. Also why are you using `bind` and not `on`? It is deprecated.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not a jQuery expert, I just know how to use my resources and understand them, I just went `bind` at first as I didn't know `on` quite much. And I don't understand why he needs to unbind? he is only trying to pass the context and he can even also access the context within the button itself which I stated from my code. I don't want to argue, I am just trying to help. have a good one

Comment: click the button "myTr" twice in your example, than click the myBtn. You will see two console.log lines since multiple onlcick events will be bound to the button now.